# How to check whether two nodes are connected?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a NetworkX graph with four nodes `(a,b,c,d)` which are partially connected. How can I check whether two nodes are adjacent? For example: How could I assert that `a` and `d` are not adjacent?

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a','b',weight=1)
G.add_edge('a','c',weight=1)
G.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)
```

I tried the following, but failed:

```
nx.is_connected(G) # I assume it checks whether edges are connected at all
nx.connected_components(G) # outputs an object that I can make no use of
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine if two nodes are [adjacent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)), or two nodes are in the same [connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))?

Comment: Your answer solved the problem I had, but I need to read through these articles to see which problem I had ;-) Actually my example displays the relationship between people. It checks whether `a` knows `b`. If an edge exists, they know each other, otherwise not.

Comment: Feel free to correct terminology or my question, if it is not to the point…

Comment: I updated the question, check it out. Glad my answer was useful!

Comment: And I learnt the difference between `node` and `edge` and could solve my problem. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way to check whether two nodes are connected with NetworkX is to check whether a node `u` is a neighbor of another node `v`.

```
>>> def nodes_connected(u, v):
...     return u in G.neighbors(v)
... 
>>> nodes_connected("a", "d")
False
>>> nodes_connected("a", "c")
True
```

Note that [`networkx.is_connected`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.is_connected.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.is_connected) checks whether every node in a graph G is reachable from every other node in G. This is equivalent to saying that there is one connected component in G (i.e. `len(nx.connected_components(G)) == 1`).

Comment: Thanks, that works. Just an additional explanation, because I had to think twice as well: `G.neighbors('a')` would return the list `['c', 'b', 'd']`, and `u in ...` checks whether `u` is an element of that list…

Comment: Not sure why this simple and fundamental task is not in the APIs?

Answer (score 12):

This is the recommended way:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge('a','b',weight=1)
G.add_edge('a','c',weight=1)
G.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)

print(G.has_edge('a','d'))  # False
print('d' in G['a']) # False, faster
print('d' not in G['a']) # True
```

Comment: Never use `not x in y`, but instead the more idiomatic `x not in y`.

Answer (score 7):

I think you ask about "how to know two nodes are reachable each other"
It can be solve by this code.

```
networkx.algorithms.descendants(G, target_nodes)
```

it returns all reachable nodes from `target_nodes` in `G`.

Comment: I know this didn't answer the OP's question, but it helped me out!